# Pass multiple values on ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to pass two values from the link to PHP through ajax but i cannot pass both of them on the same time I only managed to pass 1 value at the time please help me to have a look what went wrong on the code

value i want to  pass

```
<a href='#' id='mylink' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModal1' class='mylink' name='id1' value=".$row["p_id"]." value1=".$row["source_id"]."> - click </a><br/>";
```

my ajax code

```
 $('a.mylink').click(function() {
          var data1=$(this).attr('value'); 
          var data2=$(this).attr('value1'); 
          $("#result1").html("");
          var dataString ='id1='+ data1 ; 
          var dataSource ='id2='+ data2 ; 
         //alert(dataSource)// if i alert to see value i can see that both of value are captured
          $.ajax({
               url: "some.php",
               type: "post",
               data: dataString,dataSource
               cache: false,
               success: function(data1){
                  $("#result1").html(data1);
               }

          });
       });
```

some.php where i take value

```
$id = @(intval($_POST['id1'])?? '');
$id2 = @(intval($_POST['id2'])?? '');
echo $id;
echo $id2;
```

Comment: I think you should change your `data: dataString,dataSource` to `data: { id1: data1, id2: data2 }`.

Comment: It works thansk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `$.ajax` call is invalid as it stands as `data: dataString,dataSource` is not valid inside an object. You can change it to:

```
data: dataString + '&' + dataSource,
```

or it is more clear as an object:

```
data: { id1 : data1, id2 : data2 },
```